# POSTing large file with curl

Tags: curl, playframework-2.0

I'm using `curl` to post a large text file to a Play 2.0 framework server.  My handler in play basically looks like this:

```
def receive = Action { implicit request =>
  request.body.asText match {
    case Some(body) => 
      body.split("\n") foreach doSomething
      Ok("Imported some lines!\n")
    case None => Ok("Please post some data!\n")
  }
}
```

I'm testing it out with `curl`.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-binary "@upload.txt" http://localhost:9000/receive
```

This work great with small file.  If there is no text I get the message "Please post some data!".  If `doSomething` throws an exception, Play sends it back to me.    If I send 100 lines, it works fine and tells me it "Imported some lines!".  However, if I send 500 lines then I receive neither message and Play doesn't log anything.  What is going on in this case?  Is Play actually receiving my request at some level (if so, why is it ignoring it?), or is `curl` failing to send anything?

Comment: Well, what does Wireshark say?

Comment: check your max file upload size that is allowed to you